# knitr/pandoc: article template supporting keywords: and linespacing:

Tags: r, templates, rstudio, knitr, pandoc

I'm using the latest R Studio, R 3.2.5, rmarkdown 0.9.6, which comes with pandoc 1.15.2 to write a journal article. Submission requires: `linespacing: 1.43` and a `keywords:` line just below the abstract.

When I click `Knit PDF` I get the default template `"C:\R\R-3.2.5\library\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.15.2.tex"` which **does not** support these fields in the YAML header. I see that `default-1.17.02.tex` supports `linespacing:`, but not `keywords:`.

I tried to modify the latter template to add keywords handling, which seemed pretty straight-forward. The relevant portion of the template, that I called `modified-template-1.17.0.2.tex` is

```
$if(title)$
\maketitle
$endif$
$if(abstract)$
\begin{abstract}
$abstract$
\end{abstract}
$endif$
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords---}} #1}
$if(keywords)$
    \keywords{$keywords$}
$endif$
```

I used the YAML header below, and `pandoc` found it; however, it generated `.tex` syntax errors, unrelated to the `keywords:` field.  I'm thinking that the `rmarkdown` templates are specific to the version of `pandoc`, but I have no way to tell.

can anyone help with this?

```
---
title: "My title"
author: ME
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%B %d, %Y")`'
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    template: "modified-template-1.17.0.2.tex"
keywords: Box M test, HE plots, MANOVA, graphics, ...
abstract: "This paper explores a variety of fascinating topics ... "
---
```

**Note added:**  I tried this modifying the `default-1.15.2.tex` template as described above.  My result is the same, and the error I get is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.527 {\centering \includegraphics

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

**One more test:**  I simply used a *copy* of the standard `default-1.15.2.tex` template in my local folder, with the YAML line

```
    template: "default-1.15.2.tex"
```

This also gives the same error, so I am mystified as to the cause.

Comment: why not edit the 1.15.2 template to add both keyword and linespacing support (which you can copy from the 1.17 template). Linespacing has nothing to do with pandoc support, it is pure latex, so it should work.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to the `keywords:` problem. It is admittedly a kludge, but doesn't require changing the template: Simply include the **keywords** as an additional paragraph in the abstract in the YAML header.

```
abstract: "This paper explores a variety of topics ...


**Keywords**: Box's M test; HE plots; MANOVA; graphics
"
```

To format as a separate paragraph required two blank lines

Comment: But then keywords will appear in the `\abstract{}` field and be formatted as such, although they are conceptually different. I don't think this is a good practice compared to using a keyword command

Comment: That's why I called it a kludge; but it is the only way I've found to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, one solution that seems to work is to copy `default-1.17.02.tex` to the working directory and modify it to include the keywords argument. In the renamed `modified-1.17.02.tex`, add this after the if block for the author name:

```
$if(keywords)$
    pdfkeywords={$for(keywords)$$keywords$$sep$; $endfor$},
$endif$
```

And then later in the document, after the if block for placing the abstract:

```
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords---}} #1}
$if(keywords)$
    \keywords{$keywords$}
$endif$
```

In the project Rmd file, we just need to specify that we are using our custom template, specify that graphics = true (to circumnavigate the `\includegraphics` error) and the keywords themselves:

```
---
title: "My title"
author: ME
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%B %d, %Y")`'
output:
  pdf_document:
    template: modified-template-1.17.0.2.tex
graphics: yes
keywords: keyword 1; keyword 2; et cetera
abstract: "Abstract here."
---

Body of article here.
```

Compiling yields a title page with the keywords field present:

[image: compiled test document]

EDIT: The OP also mentioned line spacing. When using the `1.17.02.tex` style (used automatically if the most recent version of Pandoc is available, either through manual install or by using the latest RStudio preview build), the ability to adjust the line spacing is done by setting `linestretch: 1` for single space, and `linestretch: 2` for double anywhere in the YAML header.