# R Markdown keywords don't appear in the document

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to knit a pdf-document but the keywords don't appear in the final document. Can someone say me what I'm doing wrong?

````
---
title: "title"
subtitle: "subtitle"
author: "author"
date: "09 04 2019"
output:
  pdf_document:
keywords: "word1, word2, word3"
footerdate: yes
abstract: 'Insert abstract here'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Introduction
````

[image]

Comment: Try `keywords: ["word1", "word2, "word3"]`

Comment: No. It does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [knitr/pandoc: article template supporting keywords: and linespacing:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978637/knitr-pandoc-article-template-supporting-keywords-and-linespacing)

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the default template `rmarkdown` provide in https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default.tex does not contain `keyword`. You can always use a custom template by copying the one in github and customize it can be the easiest way.

Comment: Is there no way to change my code, that I can add the keywords in the header?

Comment: As specified in my linked question, you can create a custom template but there is no way to simply change the R code to get the desired result.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: you can add a line to an existing header element to approximate the result you're looking for, keeping in mind the line will inherit the style of whatever element you choose to extend.  
`date: |
 | "09 04 2019"
 | "keywords: word1, word2, word3"`

Answer (score 0):

When knitting to PDF, keywords are sent to the file metadata but are not actually visible in the file. [Source](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1121)

Answer (score 0):

You can [customize the `template` for PDF generation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38024787/10215301) or [render Rmd files with `base_format: rticles::elsevier_article`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42278815/10215301).
However, there is another way to show keywords on the PDF just by adding few codes to the Rmd file:

1. Add a LaTeX code to provide the `\keyword` command (`\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords---}} #1}`) into YAML's `header-includes` key;
2. Add keywords in the text section using the LaTeX command

````
---
title: "title"
subtitle: "subtitle"
author: "author"
date: "09 04 2019"
output:
  pdf_document:
# keywords: "word1, word2, word3" # <- You don't have to add your keywords here since they only appear as the 'invisible' metadata of PDF
footerdate: yes
abstract: 'Insert abstract here'
header-includes:
  - |
    ```{=latex}
    \providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords---}} #1}
    ```
---

```{=latex}
\keywords{word1, word2, word3}
```

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Introduction
````