# Printing the value of the keywords field of the YAML header in a Markdown file as an inline list

Tags: lua, yaml, markdown, pandoc

This question is a spin-off from [Writing thanks and keywords from Markdown to docx via Pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75030993/writing-thanks-and-keywords-from-yaml-header-in-markdown-file-to-docx-document-t/75034318#75034318).

In my specific setting I am converting the contents of a Markdown file to a docx document via Pandoc. The Markdown file opens with a YAML header for certain metadata among which is a list of keywords as required by the publisher for the target docx document. This list is entered as the value of the `keywords` YAML field as per the MWE below.

My problem is that the list is printed in the target document as a paragraph list; i.e. it starts a new paragraph and each item is printed in its own paragraph. The wished for output is instead an inline list; i.e., a single (logical, not necessarily typographic) line of items (the keywords) separated by some constant delimiter (in my case, a comma, but this particular is unsubstantial).

How can this be achieved?

```
---
title: The Title
author: The Author
thanks: |
  The author wishes to thank certain support.
abstract: |
  This is the abstract.
keywords: [one, two, three, four]
---
   
# A Heading

Text body.
```

I have considered a Lua filter along the lines of

```lua
function Meta (meta)
  meta.abstract = meta.abstract .. {pandoc.Emph("Keywords: ")} .. meta.keywords
  return meta
end
```

but this returns precisely the list of keywords as a paragraph list rather than an inline list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc tries to guess what we want, but in this case we should be a bit more explicit: we intersperse comma and space separators between the keywords, then use that to construct a separate paragraph for keywords:

```lua
function Meta (meta)
  -- insert comma and space between keywords
  local keywords, sep = pandoc.Inlines{}, pandoc.Inlines ', '
  for i, kw in ipairs(meta.keywords or {}) do
    keywords:extend(kw)
    if i ~= #meta.keywords then
      keywords:extend(sep)
    end
  end

  -- Append keywords paragraph to abstract
  meta.abstract = meta.abstract ..
    {pandoc.Para({pandoc.Emph 'Keywords: '} .. keywords)}
  return meta
end
```

Comment: I am getting an error message in the form of  `/path_to_script/keywords.lua:12: bad argument #2 to 'concat' (table expected, got Block)
stack traceback:  /path_to_script/keywords.lua:12: in function 'Meta'` when I call the script from my actual setup, where `keywords.lua` is my name for the file storing the script and  `path_to_script` is just a place holder for the path to that file.

Comment: I have just checked that the same happens with my test file as per the MWE in the OP.

Comment: Oops, forgot some braces. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks so much. Building from your script, I was able to make some amends to fit my preferences and everything works perfectly.